# Not able to load static resources in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My question is simple. I am simply not able to load static resources in Spring
Below are my configuration files.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd      http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">


 <!-- Turns on support for mapping requests to Spring MVC @Controller methods
     Also registers default Formatters and Validators for use across all @Controllers -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>


<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources -->
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

<!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static resource 
requests to the container's default Servlet -->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.redefine.entertainment"></context:component-scan>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>test</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-   value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RedefineEntertainment</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RedefineEntertainment</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have put my js and css files in /webapp/resources/css and /webapp/resources/js.

I know this question has been addresses many times but I am simply not able to load static resources. I get 405 no method error on browser.

[image: Error on browser]

Tried every other solution on net. Kindly tell where am I going wrong. Really frustrated with these spring configuration files.

Comment: Issue resolved. I had created my project in eclipse with spring configured in it. May be there was some configuration conflict which was not allowing my static resources to be loaded. Moved my project to STS(Spring tool suite), now I am able to refer my static resources.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing `applicationContext*.xml` whereas your name of context file is `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-   value>
</context-param>
```

Moreover you have to read about usage of [`<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) and [`<mvc:resources>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources), from the documentation as both have a different way to serve static content, as follows:

With **`<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>`** spring dispatcher ***serve static resources under the web root (/webapp)*** using default servlet.

And with **`<mvc:resources>`** spring uses a convenient way to ***serve static resources from locations other than the web application root, including locations on the classpath.***

Talking about your configuration, as you have do not have static resources under the web root, as you mentioned:

> I have put my js and css files in /webapp/resources/css and
>   /webapp/resources/js.

You have to edit the configuration to use either one of them to serve static files and have to access in a specific way, as follows:

Considering you are using convenient way to serve static file, as below:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources -->
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

Then you have to access `CSS` and `JS` providing a path to a folder where ***`/resources` is the mapping attribute in `mvc:resources`*** tag:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/my.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/my.js" />"></script>
```

Above snippet assume you have `my.css` and `my.js` in respective folder.

Comment: by dispatcher servlet I mean. projectname-servlet.xml. That is working absolutely fine. I am able to call my other controllers, facing problem only with static resources. Instead of loading it is trying to map a controller and hence getting that error.